# DateTime To Be NULL when the value is DateTime.MinValue or it is Null

Tags: c#, datetime

In my console app I am attempting to format to `HHmmss` -> I am sure it is due to my data types but how can I have this be `NULL` when `NULL` and not display `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`?

This is my syntax

```
public static DateTime fmtLST;
public static string LST = null;        
if (LST != null)
{
  IFormatProvider format = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
  fmtLST = DateTime.ParseExact(LST, "HHmmss", format);
}

Console.WriteLine(fmtLST.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"));
```

If altered to `public static DateTime? fmtLastScanTime;` I get an error of

> 'No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

How can I have this display `NULL` instead of `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`?
Trying to account for 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM being displayed

Comment: if `fmtLST` is `null` then `fmtLST.ToString()` will raise exception

Comment: But it is never null - it will default to 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM.  I want it to return NULL not the default date/time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be but try this

```
IFormatProvider format = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
                fmtLST = DateTime.ParseExact((LST != null ? LST : null), "HHmmss", format);
```

Answer (score 3):

Nullable DateTime. A nullable DateTime can be null. The DateTime struct itself does not provide a null option. But the `"DateTime?"` nullable type allows you to assign the null literal to the DateTime type. It provides another level of indirection.

```
public static DateTime? fmtLST;
//or 
public static Nullable<DateTime> fmtLST;
```

A nullable DateTime is most easily specified using the question mark syntax

Edit:

```
Console.WriteLine(fmtLST != null ? fmtLST.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt") : "");
```

Another one could be

```
if(fmtLST == DateTime.MinValue)
{
   //your date is "01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM"
}
```

Comment: I use the fmtLST variable so I can format DateTime.ParseExact(LST, "HHmmss", format);  How would I format in  your example?

Comment: @ToastedBreadLeavesYouDead Have a look at the edited part of the solution

Comment: Do I have to use the "n/a" as the else condition?  I altered it to be null for the else condition but that returned 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

I have Found This refrence [here](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/nullable.html) when seraching for same Issue

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Nullable nullDateTime;
            //DateTime? nullDateTime = null;
            nullDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (nullDateTime != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(nullDateTime.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can go in link find more details 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` is the minimum/default value of the DateTime object, if you want to assign null to DateTime object means you have to make them as `Nullable`(as like others suggested). So the declaration of `fmtLST` should be :

```
public static DateTime? fmtLST = null; // initialization is not necessary
```

In this case you have to care about printing the output to the console. it should be something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(fmtLST.HasValue ? fmtLST.Value.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt") : "Value is null");
```

Comment: the else condition is "Value IS NULL" - I want the else to be null.

Comment: How you are planning to print `null` on the screen? in `Console.WriteLine()`

Comment: I am writing to the console to verify the value is actually NULL.  What the end result of my procedure is, is to update a SQL Server Table where I want a NULL value not the Min.Date value

Comment: Then whats wrong with that assign this to the parameter:  fmtLST.HasValue ? fmtLST.Value.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt") : DBNull)